# How can I transform a LineSeries in a WPF OxyPlot Plot?

Tags: c#, wpf, transform, oxyplot

I have an OxyPlot graph, and I want to transform one of the LineSeries in this graph.  I'd like to apply both rotation and translation transformations, but I can't get any kind of transformation to actually take place (I'm not including the model that holds the MyItems property, but it's MVVM and working correctly).

```
<oxy:Plot>
    <oxy:Plot.Axes>
        <oxy:LinearAxis Position="Bottom" Title="X"/>
        <oxy:LinearAxis Position="Left" Title="Y"/>
    </oxy:Plot.Axes>
    <oxy:Plot.Series>
        <oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource={Binding Path=MyItems}/>
    </oxy:Plot.Series>
</oxy:Plot>
```

So far, I've tried playing with the `LayoutTransform` property in the LineSeries, like so (the X and Y values are just arbitrary for testing if I can get it to move at all):

```
<oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource={Binding Path=MyItems}>
    <oxy:LineSeries.LayoutTransform>
        <TranslateTransform X="1" Y="2"/>
    </oxy:LineSeries.LayoutTransform>
</oxy:LineSeries>
```

However, nothing happens - the series displays exactly the same way with and without the `LayoutTransform` property.  I've read through the documentation, and I can't find any other properties that even appear to reference transformation, and I can't find any guide on how to actually use the `LayoutTransform` property.  Does anyone know how to achieve this, short of manually recalculating each and every point in `MyItems` in the code-behind?

I'm willing to create a transformation object in the code-behind, but I would much rather work with the XAML directly because I'll be using binding.

Note: The points in `MyItems` all have both X and Y coordinates within 0 and 1, so the problem isn't that the move is too slight for me to see.

Comment: `OxyPlot` is most likely ignoring the transform (for a good reason). If you try the same with `System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting` it does apply `RenderTransform` but not `LayoutTransform`. Nonetheless the results aren't what you're expecting anyway: the series may end up outside the chart area.

Comment: @jstreet - So does that mean I can't easily do this in `OxyPlot`?

Comment: You can't do it at all by applying a XAML transform. But it is simple enough to translate your point collection in code-behind.

Comment: OK, that's what I'll do, then.  Thanks!